# a question about the difference equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

One solution to $n^2a_{n+2}-n(n+1)a_{n+1}+a_{n}=0$ is $a_n=n$. Find the general solution.

Recalling that the differential equation of the form $x^2{y}''-x(x+1){y}'+y=0$. But actually maybe we cannot solve the differential equation of this type. Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: The proposed solution does not survive insertion into the equation. The coefficient equation for the differential equation is $$0=(n+r)(n+r-1)a_n-(n+r)a_n-(n+r-1)a_{n-1}+a_n\\=(n+r-1)^2a_n-(n+r-1)a_{n-1}.$$ This does not resemble the given coefficient equation.

Comment: This gives $r=1$, $a_n=1/n!$ and thus $y(x)=xe^x$ as first solution. The second is found via reduction-of-order and probably contains a log term.

Comment: What does this r in your equation exactly mean? I'm sorry I didn't understand your solution.

Comment: It is the extra power in a Frobenius power series $x^r\sum a_nx^n=\sum a_nx^{n+r}$. Your equation has a regular singularity, so it is not given that all solutions have normal power series expansions.

Answer (score 1):

For the DE;
$$x^2{y}''-x(x+1){y}'+y=0$$
$${y}''-y'-\dfrac {xy'-y}{x^2}=0$$
Integrate:
$$y'-y-\dfrac y x=C_1$$
Then $y=tx$
$$t'x-tx=C_1$$
$$(te^{-x})'=C_1\dfrac {e^{-x}}{x}$$

Comment: I understand your solution for the differential equation. But how to solve the difference equation given above?